# sql-server insert statement output clause doesnt work

Tags: sql-server, insert, output

I did some research and found out that the best solution to get the id of newly inserted row is output clause.I am using the insert statement output clause for the first time and couldnt figure it out.

here is my sql code. what is wrong with this sql?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MedBul_Insert_Message]      
                                              (@ParentID int, @MessageFrom varchar(500),@MessageTo varchar(500), @MessageSubject varchar(500),@MessageBody varchar(4000),@MessageIsRead int)
AS
BEGIN
    SET LANGUAGE Turkish;

Declare @message_id table (MessageID int);

insert into Messages output INSERTED.ID INTO @message_id (ParentID ,MessageFrom ,MessageSubject ,MessageBody ,MessageIsRead ) values(@ParentID ,@MessageFrom ,@MessageSubject ,@MessageBody ,@MessageIsRead );


END
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" - in what way? An error message? If so, what?

Comment: it gives this error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OUTPUT` clause should come *after* the column list:

```
insert into Messages (ParentID ,MessageFrom ,MessageSubject ,MessageBody ,MessageIsRead )
output INSERTED.ID INTO @message_id (MessageID)
values(@ParentID ,@MessageFrom ,@MessageSubject ,@MessageBody ,@MessageIsRead );
```

See the [`INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174335.aspx) documentation.

(And also, obviously, you need to actually *do* something with the contents of `@message_id` now, but I presume you've not yet written or just not shown in your question, the remainder of the stored procedure)

Comment: yes, and I was going to ask you help me to insert that message_id into another table :)

Comment: I need to write another insert statement to insert that id, can you give me a short example for that?

Comment: Work out what you want to insert into the next table as a `SELECT` statement, using `@message_id` as one of the tables in the `FROM` clause. You can then use `INSERT (...) SELECT ...` instead of `INSERT (...) VALUES ()` to change that `SELECT` into an `INSERT`.

Comment: my second insert statement is easy but I dont know how to do it? here is the insert "insert into MessagesTo (MessageID,ToProfessionalID) values()"

Comment: Technically you don't need to output into anything either, just having the output statement will return the values as expected. [Here's a code example](http://brockstaylor.com/using-output-clause-to-return-inserted-identity-value/)